# Php prepare method where should I use While loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I am new to PHP prepare method, I need some help to use while loop in the following code.

Here is the query function

```
function query($query, $bindings, $conn) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt-> execute($bindings);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    return $result ? $result : false;
}
```

and the query

```
$home_team = query('SELECT home_team FROM premier_league
                    WHERE match_date >= :current_date
                    AND pre_selected = :pre_selected
                    ORDER BY match_date LIMIT 5',
                    array('current_date' => $current_date,
                    'pre_selected' =>$pre_selected),
                    $conn);
if (empty($home_team)){
    echo "No Match Selected for Today.";
} else {
    print_r($home_team);
}
```

How and where I use while loop for this query?

Comment: foreach($result as $row)
{
   echo $row['id']
}

Comment: you need no while here but foreach

Comment: by the way `return $stmt->fetchAll();` would be enough

Comment: you could just return `$stmt` and do `foreach($stmt as $row)`

Comment: @redreggae that would be wrong idea

Comment: @YourCommonSense wrong idea? `PDOStatement` implements `Traversable` so you can do a `foreach` loop. You can do `$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` before returning.

Comment: Done with the foreach Thank You all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need no while here

```
function query($query, $bindings, $conn) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt-> execute($bindings);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
$sql = 'SELECT home_team FROM premier_league WHERE match_date >= ?
            AND pre_selected = ? ORDER BY match_date LIMIT 5';
$home_team = query($sql,array($current_date, $pre_selected), $conn);
foreach ($home_team as $row) {
    echo $row['home_team']."<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `else` block

```
else {
    print_r($home_team);
    /* here
    foreach ($home_team as $team) {
       echo $team->home_team . '<br>';
    }*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`PDOStatement` implements `Traversable` so using `fetchAll` would be a overhead.

```
function query($query, $bindings, $conn) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($bindings);
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $stmt;        
}

$home_team = query...;
foreach ($home_team as $row) {
    echo $row['home_team']."<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The idea of using a prepared query is to have the server parse the query once and create a query plan once. This is useful for queries that you execute repeatedly, only changing the parameter values.
Accordingly:
- the prepare should be done once.
- the execute should be done inside the loop.

If you are executing a query once in a while, then the prepare overhead is not worth it.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement that confirms what I previously said.